# trying to make an ecommerce website in asp.net mvc5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, e-commerce, code-first

I am trying to make an ecommerce website using entity framework code first but am having a problem with the basket I don't need add bank accounts or any kind the payment method is pay on delivery I got the Icon ready as a button

```
<dd>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Add","Basket",new { id = this.Model.Id },new { @class = "btn btn-primary"})
                    </dd>
```

once clicked it will activate the action method

```
public ActionResult Basket(int Id)
    {
        PB.basket(Id);
        return View();
    }
```

witch will activate a method called basket

```
public void basket(int Id)
    {
        List<Basket> bst = new List<Basket>();
        var user = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
        var prd = db.Products.Where(p => p.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
        bst.Add(new Basket()
        {
            Price = prd.Price,
            ProductId = prd.Id,
            Count = 1,
        }) ;
    }
```

here are the classes witch the database for it is created
using identity

```
  public class users
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

 public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
    }
 public class Basket
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser user { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Product> products { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApplicationUser> users { get; set; }
    }
```

please help

Comment: I don't see a question here, what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I'm creating a shopping cart I created the database but am having trouble here I thing I need to join to tables here